# Add a key to the dict if not exist, then rename this key

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a list of dicts:

```
ls = [{'id': 1, 'a1': 2, 'a2': 3}, {'id':2, 'a2':4}, {'id':3, 'a2':5}]
```

where `a1` doesn't exist in some dicts

I want to set `a1` to 0 in these dicts where `a1` is missing and change the key name `a1` to `b1` in all dicts. Here is the code I come up with

```
for l in ls:
    l.setdefault('a1', 0)
    l['b1'] = l.pop('a1')
```

I'm wondering is it possible to make it more efficient, as I need to run this piece of code millions of times. Any improvements would be appreciated.

Comment: why you not simply use code: `l.setdefault('b1', l.pop('a1') if 'a1' in l else 0)`

Comment: On my old notebook running your code on a list containing a million dictionaries takes only half a second.  If your code does anything else other than this, it seems pretty unlikely that it's going to be a bottleneck.  Finding more elegant code can be fun, but I wouldn't worry about efficiency on this scale.

Comment: @DSM, I will run it on a VPS which only has 1cpu and 0.5G RAM. Each list will have hundreds up to 10k  dicts, and I have tens of millions of this kind of lists to run. Say I have 10m lists and somehow I can save 0.01 seconds each, this will save me 27.78 hours. So any improvements could be significant.

Comment: @Harrison: based on results from the `timeit` module the solution in my answer should provide approx 20% improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a slight improvement which exploits the fact that `dict.pop()` can take an argument to return as the default if the key is not in the dictionary:

```
ls = [{'id': 1, 'a1': 2, 'a2': 3}, {'id':2, 'a2':4}, {'id':3, 'a2':5}]
for d in ls:
    d['b1'] = d.pop('a1', 0)

>>> ls
[{'a2': 3, 'id': 1, 'b1': 2}, {'a2': 4, 'id': 2, 'b1': 0}, {'a2': 5, 'id': 3, 'b1': 0}]
```